# Is $C[0,1]$ locally Compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

> I'm asked to use the function $f_n(x)=nx$ for $0\le x\le \frac{1}{n}$ and $f_n(x)=1$ for $\frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1$.

I'm not familiar with Functional Analysis.

Comment: Actually every locally compact Banach space is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these functions are in the ball of radius $1$ centered at $0$. They don't converge uniformly to any continuous function, nor does any subsequence converge uniformly to any continuous function (why?). Hence the ball is not precompact. Conclude from there.